# unable to set the first record as selected in html table

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, radio-button

I have HTML table where i am displaying the list of account records and based on the selection of record i am updating the details . I am trying the set the first record radio button as selected on load .

**HTML**

```
<template for:each={accData} for:item="acc">
<tr key={acc.Id}>
<td >
  <div>
     <lightning-input type="checkbox" name="radioButtonSelect" value={acc.Id} checked onchange={handleChangeRadio}></lightning-input>
  </div>
 </td>
<td >
 <div>
     <lightning-formatted-text value={acc.Name} ></lightning-formatted-text>
 </div>
</td>
```

**JS**

```
connectedCallback(){
    this.LoadPage();
}

LoadPage() {
    accRecords()
        .then(result => {
            this.accData = result;;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });
}


handleChangeRadio(event){        
    this.accId = event.target.value;
    console.log('=======oppid=='+event.target.value);
    this.accRecord = [];
    for(let i in this.accData) {
        if(this.accId == this.accData[i].Id) {
                this.accRecord = this.accData[i];
        }
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a new `checked` property to the `result` before assigning it to `accData`.

```js
accRecords()
    .then(result => {
      this.accData = result.map((account, index) => {
        return {
          checked: index === 0 ? true: false,
          ...account 
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

You can then bind the checked property to the attribute.

```html
<lightning-input ... checked={acc.checked} ...></lightning-input>
```

Comment: Its working . But on load can i set the default value selected radio value to accRecord . As i am sending the accRecord value to another componet

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the radio button, use `lightning-radio-group` or `<input type="radio">`. Currently, you are using the checkbox. The main difference is that for a radio group with the same name it is possible to select only one radio. The checkboxes can be checked multiple.

---

in LWC there are no expressions in HTML markup (opposite in AURA), so all preparation for data rendering should be done on the JS side.

**JS**

```
....
connectedCallback() {
    this.LoadPage();
}

LoadPage() {
    accRecords()
        .then(result => {
            this.accData = result.map((element, index) => ({...element, default: index === 0}));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });
}


handleChangeRadio(event) {
    this.accRecord = this.accData.find(element => (element.Id === event.target.value));
    console.log(this.accRecord);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<template for:each={accData} for:item="acc">
    <tr key={acc.Id}>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="radioButtonSelect" value={acc.Id} checked={acc.default} onchange={handleChangeRadio} />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <lightning-formatted-text value={acc.Name}></lightning-formatted-text>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: I have tried this . On load the first value is set but on on radio change , the radio button is not selected

Answer (score 0):

In the html just add the checked property like below and in your you have to maintain the index variable.

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.tests}" var="test" indexVar="index">

  <input type="radio"  value = "{!test.Id}"  
                               onclick="{!c.handleRadioClick}" checked="{!if(index == 0, true, false)}"/>
```